# Bower dependency updates available

Tags: javascript, frontend, bower

Is there an automated way of checking to see if the front-end dependencies listed in my `bower.json` file have updates available without actually updating the dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is as easy as running `bower list`.  All of your dependencies are listed with available updates highlighted.